# bullet won't draw in alien invasion game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

so I'm still working on the alien invasion game in python crash course. after I fixed the ship bug now my bullet won't draw onto the screen I'll just give you the code. Hopefully you will know what the problem is.

alien_invasion.py:

```
import pygame
import sys
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet


class AlienInvasion:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self.bullets.update()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = True
                if event == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    self._fire_bullet()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = False
            if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                self.width = pygame.display.get_surface().get_width()
                self.height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_height()
                self.settings.display = pygame.display.set_mode((int(self.width), int(self.height)), pygame.RESIZABLE)
                self.ship = Ship(self)

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        new_bullet = Bullet(self)
        self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.settings.display.fill(self.settings.rgb_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

settings.py:

```
import pygame
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics


class Settings:

    def __init__(self):
        loop = True
        while loop is True:
            print(f"Set Window Size(Type 'default' to use default 1920*1080, type 'full' to use full screen)")
            self.screenX = input()
            if self.screenX == 'default':
                self.screen_size = (1920, 1080)
                self.display_mode = 'Window'
                loop = False
            elif self.screenX == 'full':
                self.display_mode = 'Full'
                loop = False
            elif self.screenX.isdigit():
                print("X")
                self.screenY = input()
                self.screen_size = (int(self.screenX), int(self.screenY))
                self.display_mode = 'Window'
                loop = False
            else:
                print("You either type a integer, 'default' or 'full'")
        loop = True
        while loop is True:
            self.R = input("\nSet RGB Color(type 'default' to use default color)"
                           "\nR: ")
            if self.R == 'default':
                self.R = 59
                self.G = 61
                self.B = 151
                loop = False
            elif self.R.isdigit():
                while loop is True:
                    if int(self.R) <= 255:
                        self.G = input("G: ")
                        loop = False
                    else:
                        print("Choose between 0 and 255")
                        self.R = input("\nSet RGB Color(type 'default' to use default color)"
                                       "\nR: ")
                loop = True
                while loop is True:
                    if int(self.G) <= 255:
                        self.B = input("B: ")
                        loop = False
                    else:
                        print("Choose between 0 and 255")
                        self.G = input("\nG: ")
                loop = True
                while loop is True:
                    if int(self.B) <= 255:
                        loop = False
                    else:
                        print("Choose between 0 and 255")
                        self.B = input("\nB: ")
            else:
                print("Type an integer or 'default'")
        self.rgb_color = (int(self.R), int(self.G), int(self.B))
        if self.display_mode == 'Window':
            self.display = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screen_size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
        elif self.display_mode == 'Full':
            self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1)), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.display.fill(self.rgb_color)
        loop = True
        while loop is True:
            self.ship_speed = input("Set ship speed, (0 - 5) ")
            self.float_ship_speed = float(self.ship_speed)
            if self.float_ship_speed <= 5:
                loop = False
            else:
                print("Type a number between 0 and 5")
```

ship.py:

```
import pygame


class Ship:

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.display = ai_game.settings.display
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.display_rect = ai_game.settings.display.get_rect()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('SpaceShip.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = self.display_rect.midbottom

        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right:
            self.x += self.settings.float_ship_speed
        if self.moving_left:
            self.x -= self.settings.float_ship_speed
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def blitme(self):
        self.display.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

bullet.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Bullet(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.ai_game = ai_game
        self.bullet = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
        self.screen = ai_game.settings.display
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.midbottom = ai_game.ship
        self.rect = self.bullet.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = ai_game.ship.rect.midbottom

        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.settings.bullet_speed
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.bullet, self.rect)
```

it's my first time making a game, so a lot of bugs are expected

Comment: For someone to help you, they'd probably have to copy-paste all of this code into different files, find image files to work with, run it, and get back to you. That's why people expect you to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So, can you make a bullet that goes up the screen, without a ship or anything else? You might also add a line somewhere, say in the `Bullet.update()` method that prints the bullet's y value. Maybe it's on the screen but not moving?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue comes from the code in `bullet.update()`:

```py
    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.settings.bullet_speed
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

You're changing the value of `self.y` by the value assigned to `bullet_speed`. But I don't see where `bullet_speed` is defined. I don't see that attribute in your `Settings` class.

(I saw this just after posting the comment on your question. In the future, you're much more likely to get answers if you can provide a much simpler version of your question. In trying to create that simpler version, you'd probably notice that `bullet_speed` was never defined.)

Comment: Yes, I found that as well, I accidentally deleted the self.bullet_speed when I changed the bullet from a gray rectangle into a picture of a 5.56 NATO bullet, but the problem is that the bullet won't appear on the screen